# How to disable the output of set command in matlab Command Window?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to `set` a property of graphics object and when I execute my code, I am getting the list of properties of that graphics object. I tried to add semicolon in the end of `set` command but it is not helping me. Is there a way to avoid getting output of set command in command window?

```
BackgroundColor
Color
DisplayName
EdgeColor
Editing: [ on | off ]
FontAngle: [ {normal} | italic | oblique ]
FontName
FontSize
FontUnits: [ inches | centimeters | normalized | {points} | pixels ]
FontWeight: [ light | {normal} | demi | bold ]
HorizontalAlignment: [ {left} | center | right ]
LineStyle: [ {-} | -- | : | -. | none ]
LineWidth
Margin
Position
Rotation
String
Units: [ inches | centimeters | normalized | points | pixels | characters | {data} ]
Interpreter: [ latex | {tex} | none ]
VerticalAlignment: [ top | cap | {middle} | baseline | bottom ]

ButtonDownFcn: string -or- function handle -or- cell array
Children
Clipping: [ {on} | off ]
CreateFcn: string -or- function handle -or- cell array
DeleteFcn: string -or- function handle -or- cell array
BusyAction: [ {queue} | cancel ]
HandleVisibility: [ {on} | callback | off ]
HitTest: [ {on} | off ]
Interruptible: [ {on} | off ]
Parent
Selected: [ on | off ]
SelectionHighlight: [ {on} | off ]
Tag
UIContextMenu
UserData
Visible: [ {on} | off ]
```

I want to avoid getting this output in command window. I am using following code:

```
p = mtit ('Global Title') ;
set (p) ;
```

mtit is method found on *Matlab Central FileExchange* in order to display the common Title for subplots.

Comment: Which line of code causes the output?

Comment: set(xyz), xyz is getting from a method.

Comment: If the above text is the output, could you please post your code as well, so we can try to figure out where the problem is?

Comment: Ok, I edit my question. Please wait for a while. Thanks

Comment: It would help if you posted your whole program. Just showing one method won't help much.

Comment: Thats all, I am doing.

Comment: There needs to be some figure, otherwise the code does not work. I tried to initialise a simple plot, but get an error as well. `Error using set
Conversion to double from struct is not possible.` No idea what you did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `set(p)` does not set any property of `p`. The correct syntax for actually setting a property of `p` is

```
 set( p, 'PropertyName', Value )
```

When typing only `set(p)` you get all property-value information typed out (which you don't want)...